# Why SNS can't send push notifications if the SNS endpoint is disabled?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS SNS to send push notifications to apple devies.

According to AWS Document, SNS does not send push notifications anymore.  if the SNS endpoint is disabled.

It can happened when user does reinstall IOS app.

so We change the value of endpoint from disabled to enabled every time with using AWS-CLI.

In my opinion, I think this is very inefficient job.

We would like to improve this job.
any good idea?

I would like advice people has experience in running a IOS app service with using AWS SNS.

Answer (score 0):

SNS is reporting to you that the endpoint is disabled because Apple is telling SNS that the endpoint is disabled.  When SNS reports that the endpoint is disabled, that tells you that you should stop sending notifications to the endpoint because the user has likely uninstalled the app or something like that.

Current best practice seems to be to delete/disable the endpoint in your database when SNS reports that the endpoint is disabled, and get a new endpoint each time the user installs the app.